# Is it possible to retrieve parameters in module.config

Tags: angularjs

just started to study AngularJS.

Is it possible to retrieve parameters in module.config in order to resolve routing? **In the code below my $routeParams.id parameter is undefined**. ...or parameters are available only in module.controller. What's wrong in this code?

```
var testApp = angular.module("testApp", ["ngRoute"]).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/ActivityModify/:id?", {
            templateUrl: "AngTemplates/ActivityModify.html"
            , controller: "activityModifyController"
            , controllerAs: "actModCtrl"
            , resolve: {    
                ActivityModify: function ($http, $routeParams) {

                    var config = {
                        params: { "id": $routeParams.id }
                    };

                    return $http.get("WS/ActivitiesService.asmx/GetActivityById", config)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            return response.data;
                        })

                }
            }
        })
```

@devqon:
I have something like this in html:

```
 <li ng-repeat="act in actAllCtrl.ActivitiesAll">
                    <!-- drag handle -->
                    <!--<span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    </span>-->
                    <!-- checkbox -->
                    <!--<input type="checkbox" value="">-->
                    <!-- todo text -->
                    <h5>
                        <span class="text">
                            <!--Design a nice theme-->
                            Titolo: {{act.ActivityTitle}}
                        </span>
                    </h5><br />
                    Stato: {{act.ActivityState}}<br />
                    Descrizione: {{act.ActivityDescription}}
                    <!-- Emphasis label -->
                    <!--<small class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 mins</small>-->
                    <!-- General tools such as edit or delete-->
                    <div class="tools">
                        <a class="fa fa-edit" href="ActivityModify/{{act.id}}"></a>
                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

-->RESOLUTION! just to clear what worked for me, as mentioned by @Alon Eitan answer

> can use $route.current.params to access the new route's parameters

so I modified like this:

```
 ActivityModify: function ($http, $route) {

                    var config = {
                        params: { "id": $route.current.params.id }
                    };
```

and solved.

Comment: Where are you calling this route? Do you pass in the id there?

Comment: @devqon: I edited the question...

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams):

*Note that the $routeParams are only updated after a route change completes successfully. This means that you **cannot rely** on $routeParams being correct in **route resolve functions**. Instead you can use $route.current.params to access the new route's parameters.*

So, inject `$location` instead of `$routeParams`, and get the parameter like this (Edit: won't work, read my edit note after the code snippet):

```
var params = $location.search();
var config = {
    params: { "id": params.id }
};
```

**Edit**: Thanks for correcting me in the comments, you should actually use `$route.current.params.id` as written it the doc I myself provided :|

Also, you're using a simple `href` attribute, and you should change it to [ngHref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) when combining it with angular expression:

```
<a class="fa fa-edit" ng-href="ActivityModify/{{act.id}}"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified ng-href. Very good. But didn't worked for me $location.search(), instead was useful $route.current.params, I injected $route, then I found my id in $route.current.params.id!!! Thx!

Comment: @Falco Thanks for correcting me. I have added it to the answer for future users that might find it helpful